# Cannot add new program in VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

> **ERROR**:"System.Collections.Generic.RandomizedStringEqualityComparer 不是 GenericTypeDefinitiono。只能对Type.lsGenericTypeDefinition 为True的类型调用 MakeGenericType。"

1.It works well when I open the software

2.[I was trying to set up a new win32 console program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzol4.png)

3.I click the third botton "完成",which means compeletment

4.[Then it will display the error information.And the file will be created but cannot be opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxPWu.png)

Comment: I have solved the problem by downloding a patch on official website of Microsoft.

Comment: Which patch is that, then? Give your solution to help [others](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40192852/560648).

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this happened to me in VS 2012 because something corrupted Update 4, reinstalling it fixed the problem.